# How to remove subdirectory in linux?

Tags: linux

I created `mkdir -p cat1/cat2/cat3` and I want to remove subdirectory cat2 and cat3. I tried to do it like this `rmdir - p cat2/cat3` but it showed me an error:

> "this catalog and file don't exist"

Comment: Is this `this catalog and file don't exist` really an error you get? What implementation of `rmdir` are you using?

Answer (score 1):

With `-p`, rmdir removes the whole path, so the path must start at `cat2`, but there's `cat1` between your current directory and `cat2`, so change the current directory first:

```
cd cat1
rmdir -p cat2/cat3
```

Alternatively, remove cat2 with everything it contains directly from the current directory:

```
rm -rf cat1/cat2
```

Note that this removes the directories even if they aren't empty.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the parent directory as well.

```
rm -rf cat1/cat2
```

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
rm -r your directory name
```